# Horizontal Menu website - Visual Studio c# - html

Tags: html, menu, web

How can I make an horizontal menu in my website? I write this code and my menu appears in vertical. Thanks.

```
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This question isn't relevant with c#, don't tag it next time..

Answer (score 2):

If you want, you could use an asp:menu

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

(This question was previously tagged with C#, so I'm assuming its asp.net - if its just html it won't work)

Otherwise if you just want a list of links, you could put them in a table in the same row

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="">item1</a></td>
<td><a href="">item2</a></td>
..
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either `li{display:inline-block;}` or `li {float:left}` or that table method you've got in previous answer. All work.